# How can we add sounds, in a memory card, in Android?

Tags: android

How can we add sounds, in a memory card, in Android?

Comment: i have added sound file into sdcard and i can also see there is a sound file in sdcard from DDMS but dont know how to get that sound file

Comment: Are you wanted to know how to get these file in android by code or do you wanna know how to add file?

Comment: if you tell me both then it will be better and please specify the how to give path to get sound file from sdcard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will add all the media file available on sdcard:

```
    private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
    public List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();

    private void updateSongList() 
    {
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (home.listFiles( new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) 
        {
            for (File file : home.listFiles( new Mp3Filter())) 
            {
                songs.add(file.getName());
            }                       
        }
    }
```

By using file explorer you can transfer the media files from your system to sdcard.